# Is there any way to create measure tool (area and length) using Ext JS 6, GeoExt 3 and Openlayers 4?

Tags: openlayers, geoext, ext-js

I am building a web GIS application using Ext JS 6.0, GeoExt 3 and Openlayers 4.3.0. I want to make measure area and measure length buttons so when I activate button I can draw polygon or line and get area or length. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: It can be done in OL4 https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/measure.html

Comment: @Mike I saw that example but I am looking for a way to make this tool work within ExtJS  app. Is there any way to embed this method in a some kind of ext.button object?